# QByteArray char by char Analysis

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, char, qbytearray

```
QByteArray Reception = client->read(client->bytesAvailable()) ;
char* reci = Recepcton.data();
if( reci[0] == "V" )
{
     ui->lcdNumber_Distance->value( (int) atoi(reci[1]) );
}
```

Can someone explain why the if line shows: 
"error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'" in the Qt console ?

I tried changing to:  `const char* reci = Recepcion.data();`   But then it shows:
"error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'const int*' in initialization"

Comment: You use single quotes to denote a character literal, not double quotes.  What you're doing in your code is comparing a single character to a string literal, exactly as the error describes.

Comment: How can i fix it ? I want to know Reception´s content

Comment: What do you want to see?  The first character in the string or the entire string?  It is not clear as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to see the entire String. DanaYan´s anser was helpfull to solve char* conversion error. Now im just dealing with atoi showing     error: no matching function for call to 'QLCDNumber::value(int)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: QByteArray has a member function constData(), so you could do this

```
const char* reci = Recepcton.constData();
```

Question 2: "V" is a string while reci[0] is a char, you could not *compare* them. As the comment mentioned, you should

```
reci[0] == 'V'
```